# How to connect multiple cells and can it be modified with any connected cell?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

Currently, I'm working on an inventory list and I have several items that use the same product. I need a way to change the quantity of all items with the same product in each cell.

I understand that I could use, for example, Cell C1 to fx=C7, but that means I would have to only use C7 to change every single product.

How could I have all cells that use the same product to be linked together to always have the same quantity? No matter which cell I change.

If I make C1 to fx=C7, I cannot change C1's number because it would delete its formula. I have up to 5-8 different products I want to adjust the quantity of but I don't want to use just one cell. I want to use any cell I'm working on at the moment, and for all cells which I have connected to be updated.

Comment: You will need vba in a worksheet_change event.

Comment: Well, how should I get this and apply it to my excel sheet?

Comment: you would open the code for that sheet, and then write the code that will do what you need.  When you get stuck, bring the code back and ask a specific question regarding the error that the code is producing.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me or teach me to code site.

Comment: Completely understandable, thank you very much Scott